Security Onion VM not picking up traffic from mirrored port
I have the following set up: my PC is connected to two ports on the Netgear switch (2 and 7) via two NICs, and the switch is configured to mirror ports 3 & 4 to port 7. A Security Onion VM on VirtualBox has two Network adapters - one for each physical NIC - in Bridged mode, with the adapter connected to the switch's mirror port.
I can access Security Onion's web interface, but the Alerts tab shows nothing. What more needs to be configured for this set up to work, either on the SO side or the switch side?
